# Prometheus service discovery with Docker

Tags: docker, monitoring, prometheus, service-discovery

My goal is to use Prometheus to monitor several microservices that can replicate or migrate.

I've seen a video of 2017 that says the only solution was through DNS A records, but it does not solve cross-Docker-network pulling, making the migration between different networks impossible right?

I would like you if you know if there is already a solution for this? (I didn't find). If not, is "file_sd_config" the best way to go? With this I'm able to change the file while having prometheus to read the updated file periodically.

Thanks!